# How can i get these 3 divs to go side by side and lined up in the middle?

Tags: html, css

[image: Mine looks like this as of now]
the 3 divs starts at < div class="ads" > that would be the main div of the 3

```css
/*
Colors:

Text: 1A1A1A
Green: #00B172
White: #FFF

*/
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 35vw;
}

nav > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #070707;
}


.logo-spotify{
    height: auto;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}




.start{
    background-image: url(../images/landing.jpg);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 850px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.start-texts-Music{
    color: white;
    margin: 5vh 0;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.start-texts-Para{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

h2{
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ads{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 30px;
}

.ads-block{
    /* display: block;
    justify-content: center;  */
}

.ads-text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #06bc7d;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.ads-desc{
    margin: 3vh 0 30vh 0;
}

.bottom{
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #06bc7d;
    margin: 0 2vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}

h3{
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    margin: 0 52vw 0 10vw;
    
} 

.bottom-title{
    display: flex;
    width: 23vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Spotify Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img
        class="logo-spotify"
        src="images/spotify-logo.png"
        alt="logo-spotify"
      />
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Premium</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="start">
      <h1 class="start-texts-Music">Music for everyone.</h1>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Spotify is now free on mobile, tablet and computer.
      </p>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Listen to the right music, wherever you are.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2>What’s on Spotify?</h2>
    <div class="ads">
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/music-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Millions of Songs</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">There are millions of songs on Spotify</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img
          src="images/high-quality-icon.png"
          alt=""
          height="auto"
          width="150px"
        />
        <p class="ads-text">HD Music</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">Listen to music as if you were listening live</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/devices-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Stream Everywhere</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">
          Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h3>It’s as yeezy as Kanye West.</h3>
      <div>
        <p class="bottom-title">search</p>
        <p class="bottom-title">
          Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Discover Help Download Music for everyone. Spotify is now free on mobile,
      tablet and computer. Listen to the right music, wherever you are. What’s
      on Spotify? Millions of Songs There are millions of songs on Spotify HD
      Music Listen to music as if you were listening live Stream Everywhere
      Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer It’s as yeezy as Kanye
      West. Search Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
      Browse Check out the latest charts, brand new releases and great playlists
      for right now. Discover Enjoy new music every Monday with your own
      personal playlist. Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is for a school project. I cant seem line them up and centered with the top title "whats on spotify". This is what the final product should look like [image: here] I have it in 3 divs into all one big div. I feel like its one of the classes thats messing up with flexbox but im not sure. i would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You have more than 3 divs in your HTML. Which divs are you mentioning?

Comment: sorry at the class name "ads" that would be the main div of the 3 @NickVu

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck the margins and padding.

try to set the below margin of `.ads-desc` the same as the top margin and set the padding for the `.ads-block` to resolve it.

```css
/*
Colors:

Text: 1A1A1A
Green: #00B172
White: #FFF

*/
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 35vw;
}

nav > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #070707;
}


.logo-spotify{
    height: auto;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}




.start{
    background-image: url(../images/landing.jpg);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 850px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.start-texts-Music{
    color: white;
    margin: 5vh 0;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.start-texts-Para{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

h2{
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ads{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 30px;
    border : 1px solid black;
}

.ads-block{
padding : 15vh 0;
}

.ads-text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #06bc7d;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.ads-desc{
    margin: 3vh 0 3vh 0;
}

.bottom{
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #06bc7d;
    margin: 0 2vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}

h3{
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    margin: 0 52vw 0 10vw;
    
} 

.bottom-title{
    display: flex;
    width: 23vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Spotify Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img
        class="logo-spotify"
        src="images/spotify-logo.png"
        alt="logo-spotify"
      />
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Premium</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="start">
      <h1 class="start-texts-Music">Music for everyone.</h1>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Spotify is now free on mobile, tablet and computer.
      </p>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Listen to the right music, wherever you are.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2>What’s on Spotify?</h2>
    <div class="ads">
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/music-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Millions of Songs</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">There are millions of songs on Spotify</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img
          src="images/high-quality-icon.png"
          alt=""
          height="auto"
          width="150px"
        />
        <p class="ads-text">HD Music</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">Listen to music as if you were listening live</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/devices-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Stream Everywhere</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">
          Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h3>It’s as yeezy as Kanye West.</h3>
      <div>
        <p class="bottom-title">search</p>
        <p class="bottom-title">
          Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Discover Help Download Music for everyone. Spotify is now free on mobile,
      tablet and computer. Listen to the right music, wherever you are. What’s
      on Spotify? Millions of Songs There are millions of songs on Spotify HD
      Music Listen to music as if you were listening live Stream Everywhere
      Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer It’s as yeezy as Kanye
      West. Search Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
      Browse Check out the latest charts, brand new releases and great playlists
      for right now. Discover Enjoy new music every Monday with your own
      personal playlist. Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

May it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to the pic center,you can try add a style.`<img />`  is inline ,so `text-align` is useful

```css
.ads-block{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
.ads-block{
    /* display: block;
    justify-content: center;  */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This will create a flex column and align the elements within the column to the center. Hope this helps:)